# Warning messages for all of my functions using pointers. Expected 'int*' but argument is of type 'int (*)[10]'

Tags: c, arrays, function-call

The code works fine I'm just worried about the warning messages I'm getting, would there be a way to make them not appear? Is there any reason to be worried about them? Also farther down in the code I don't quite understand what I did or why it worked. It wasn't working before so I looked up what other people did with pointers and it works now

```
Warning passing argument 1 of 'readarray' from incompatible pointer type [-wincomp
readarray(&a);
          ^
note: expected 'int*' but argument is of type 'int(*)[10]'
void readarray (int*);
     ^
```

This is the warning message, I get it for each of my functions^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

I understand why it's having issues, I think, but I don't understand how I could change anything

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define n 10

void readarray (int*);
int findmaxvalue(int*);
void reversearray(int*, int*);
void printarray(int*);

int main(void)
{
        int a[n], i, b[n];

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
                a[i] = 0;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
                b[i] = 0;
        }

        readarray(&a);
        findmaxvalue(&a);
        reversearray(&a, &b);
        printarray(&b);

    return 0;
    }


void readarray (int *a)
{
        int *q;

        q = a;
        printf("Enter up to 10 numbers. Terminate by entering a 0\n");
```

Right here, why can't I use 'a' instead of 'a+n'

```
        for(q = a; q < a+n; q++)
        {
                scanf("%d", q);
                if (*q == 0)
                        break;
        }
        printf("\n");
}


int findmaxvalue(int *a)
{
        int i, max;

        max = a[0];
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
                if (a[i] > max)
                        max = a[i];
        }
        printf("The highest element in the array is: %d\n\n", max);
        return max;
}


void reversearray(int *a, int *b)
{
        int *i, *j, t;

        for (i = a; i < a+n; i++)
        {
                for (j = i + 1; j < a+n; j++)
                {
                        if (*j < *i)
                        {
                                t = *j;
                                *j = *i;
                                *i = t;
                        }
                }
        }

        for (i = a + n - 1, j = b; i > a; i--, j++)
        {
                *j = *i;
        }
}

void printarray(int *b)
{
        int *q;

        q = b;
        printf("The reversed array in descending order is:\n");
        for (q = b; q < b+n; q++)
        {
                printf("%d  ", *q);
        }
}
```

Comment: `Right here, why can't I use 'a' instead of 'a+n'`...what do you mean?

Comment: My bad I meant to say 'Why can't I use 'n' instead of having to use 'a+n''

Answer (score 3):

I think the error message is pretty self-describing.

In your code, `a` is an array type, having `int [10]`. You pass `&a`, which is of type *pointer to an array of 10 `int`s*, or, `int (*)[10]` which is not the same type as a pointer to `int`, i.e., `int *`. Hence the compiler screams.

As array type variables decay to the pointer to the first element of the array while passed as function arguments, you should call your function like

```
 readarray(a);
```

Comment: I understand that they aren't the same type, but that's how my professor showed us how to pass arrays as an argument or I guess a pointer to an array? The program could be written differently but we had to use pointers. I want to know if there is a proper way of passing an array to a function, or if I'm doing it right and I'm being worried for nothing. This entire pointer business is super confusing.